# Leibniz rule with indicator functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, distribution-theory

Note that on Wikipedia, the Lebesgue version of Leibniz rule states that

> Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbf{R}$, and $\Omega$ be a measure space. Suppose $f: X \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ satisfies the following conditions
>
> 1. $f(x, \omega)$ is a Lebesgue-integrable function of $\omega$ for each $x \in X$.
> 2. For almost all $\omega \in \Omega$, the partial derivative $f_x$ exists for all $x \in X$.
> 3. There is an integrable function $\theta: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ such that $\left|f_x(x, \omega)\right| \leq \theta(\omega)$ for all $x \in X$ and almost every $\omega \in \Omega$.
>    Then, for all $x \in X$,
>    $$
>    \frac{d}{d x} \int_{\Omega} f(x, \omega) d \omega=\int_{\Omega} f_x(x, \omega) d \omega .
>    $$

Note that if we let $X = \Omega = [0,1]$, with $f(\omega,x) = \mathbb{1}\{\omega < x\}$, then we know that $f_x(\omega,x) \stackrel{\text{a.s}}{=}0$ and so
$$ \int_{\Omega} f_x(\omega,x) d\omega = 0.$$
However,

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_{\Omega} f(\omega,x) d\omega = \frac{d}{dx}x = 1. $$

My guess is that I need to use the distributional derivative of the indicator function rather than the normal derivative, but I have not studied distributions or delta functions formally before, and don't see why the regular almost-everywhere derivative does not apply here.

Comment: Note that condition 3 requires $f_x$ to be dominated by an integrable function *for all $x$*. When you justify the exchange of the limit and integral, this is necessary in order to apply the dominated convergence theorem. (You can likely weaken this result to include absolutely continuous functions, to allow nondifferentiability on measure zero sets, but the key is that you need to ensure the derivative behaves nicely). In your case, the derivative is a Dirac delta, which is not an integrable function, nor is it dominated by one.

Comment: I see, so the null set on which domination holds true should be fixed for every $x \in X$. Otherwise I guess there are uncountable many $x \in X$ so a different null set of each could add up to a set of positive measure! This is very much like the issue of writing down the abstract conditional expectation as an integral with respect to a conditional measure, where the almost sure qualifiers in the countable additivity of conditional probabilities cause problems.

Comment: I guess this violates condition 2 as well. If you write your comment as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.